# Disable E_STRICT errors in php.ini

Tags: php

I am trying to disable E_STRICT errors directly in the php.ini. Here's what I put:

```
display_errors = On
error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_STRICT
```

My question is:

- 1 - why is it still (after restarting apache) reporting E_STRICT errors?
- 2 - when display_errors is set to `Off` **are the errors still being logged to apache error logs**?

Comment: have you restarted your apache server?

Comment: 1. The value can be set / changed in your code, do you use a framework? 2. Normally yes.

Answer (score 0):

in your script

```
error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_STRICT
```

change to

```
error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_STRICT
```

If you failed to  access to the php.ini, you can potentially put this in your .htaccess file:

```
php_value error_reporting 30711
```

i wish it will works ...Thank you

Answer (score 0):

try

```
error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_STRICT
```

using .htaccess file:

```
php_value error_reporting 30711
```

and restart your apache server

Answer (score 0):

It is still doing so because I have added a custom error handler using `set_error_handler`. In that case, as the manual says:

> error_reporting() settings will have no effect and your error handler
>   will be called regardless

The second question still remains though ;)